AWS Streaming lambda not setting CORS header for OPTIONS request
I am trying to use AWS Lambda response stream to stream some text to front end. I have a very basic lambda below:
//@ts-ignore
exports.handler = awslambda.streamifyResponse(
  async (event: any, responseStream: any, context: any) => {
    const httpResponseMetadata = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',   <- returning CORS header.
      },
    };

    //@ts-ignore
    responseStream = awslambda.HttpResponseStream.from(
      responseStream,
      httpResponseMetadata
    );

    responseStream.write('First line \n');
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
    responseStream.write('Second line \n');
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
    responseStream.write('Done!!!');
    responseStream.end();
  }
);


This lambda is currently called by its Function URL. Configuration for function URL looks like below:

Please note that in Allow methods there is no way to me to set OPTIONS :( as it is not an option (no pun intended) when trying to edit.
When I call my lambda function using curl command I get 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in response:
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 01 Apr 2024 14:27:14 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amzn-RequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< X-Amzn-Trace-Id: root=1-00000000-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
< 
First line 
Second line 
Done!!!

However, when trying to access the same function URL from a web page I am getting following error:

Is there some other way to respond with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header? I am not using API GW because to my knowledge they don't support streaming yet.

Okay so I accidentally stumbled onto the solution. I copied the options request as curl from the browser and made sure that issue persists in terminal as well. After that I compared that with the curl request that was already working for me, curl copied from browser has lot of headers. I started putting each header one by one from browser curl to working curl. As soon as I put header Access-Control-Request-Headers in curl I stopped getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response from server.
From this page it seems like these are the headers that client might request. I made a guess that if these headers are not allowed from server side, server might simply respond as not allowed. After I allowed all the headers client was requesting it started working. :)
Now I'll check which header is required by client and which is not and will try to shorten that list.
